# The MVC model's datetime format always can't be control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime-format

I'm trying to use DateTime with TextBoxFor to show n be edit ~
but one of my model's datetime format always can't be control~

**View**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassDate,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new {  @readonly = "true",style = "width:135px",type="date"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassDate,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new {  @readonly = "true",style = "width:135px"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TeacherInfo.BDay,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new {  @readonly = "true",style = "width:135px",type="date"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TeacherInfo.BDay,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new {  @readonly = "true",style = "width:135px"})
```

**Model(I have two table n using foreign key)**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> BDay { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> ClassDate { get; set; }
```

**Result**
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B53j6yH_R3ZeTjc2SmMxYS1OUkk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( model=>model.ClassDate, new { @readonly = "true", style = "width:135px", type="date", @Value = Model.ClassDate.Day + "/" + Model.ClassDate.Month + " / " + Model.ClassDate.Year})
```

I had the same problem but this really works for me....

Comment: Sir~It's doesn't work~
THe ClassDate was Nullable<System.DateTime> ,so it couldn't find Day,Month,Year as properties.
But, I found a way to made it work without update function which meant it could be auto-bidding to the column of table.
`@{DateTime x = (DateTime)Model.ClassDate};
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => x,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new {  @readonly = "true",style = "width:135px",type="date"})`